# How do I add extra DTD declarations with java DOM

Tags: java, dom, dtd, xml

My program is supposed to read an XML doc, edit it, and export it again, but when it does, it exports it without the declarations I originally included:

```
<!DOCTYPE touchégg [
<!ELEMENT touchégg (application)*>
<!ELEMENT application (gesture)>
<!ELEMENT gesture (action)>
<!ELEMENT action (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST action type CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST gesture 
    id ID #IMPLIED
    type CDATA #IMPLIED
    fingers CDATA #IMPLIED
    direction CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```

How can I add this to the top of my document?